# iOS Converting strings to date: hour is the same on two different times

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have this code to convert a string to date:

```
NSString* strToConvert;
NSDate* dtToReturn;
//...code to parse string
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy, HH:mm:ss a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    dtToReturn = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strToConvert];
```

I send it this string "08/30/16 02:22:00 PM"

and it returns this date: 2016-08-30 16:22:00 +0000

which is expected since I am +4 from GMT

But if I send it this string: "08/30/16 03:22:00 PM"

it returns the same date: 2016-08-30 16:22:00 +0000

I only pass one string at a time to the method. Am I doing something wrong in my dateformatter?

Comment: Instead of HH, use hh

Comment: Btw, first case is also wrong, 16:22:00 converted to AM/PM format is 4:22:00 PM, which means +2 GMT, not +4 GMT

Comment: ug, Friday before a holiday, the math-fu is not working. :D 
But your solution worked! Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Make it an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1):

Because `strToConvert` uses AM/PM hour time and date formatter is using 24 hour time, this leads to a wrong date conversion. Fix date formatter's `dateFormat` to use AM/PM hour time: `@"MM/dd/yy, hh:mm:ss a"`